# Error con websocket de Js

Tags: javascript, websocket

Hola estoy montando un socket del lado del cliente, con la api web que me proporciona js:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5500');
ws.onopen = () => {
    alert("conectado")
}
```

La url en donde corro mi index es la siguiente:

```
http://localhost:5500/index.html
```

Pero me lanza este error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5500/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

No tengo ni la menor idea de que estoy haciendo mal en esto tan sencillo, ya que mi url es la del servidor que estoy corriendo:(

Comment: ¿Haz configurado el socket también en tu servidor? ¿Qué estas usando en la parte del server?

Comment: Regularmente para estos casos debe de existir una aplicación que levante un Web Socket en el puerto deseado, sugiero que amplíes más el escenario para mayor información.

Comment: Para serte sincero soy nuevo en este tema de los WebSockets, solo estaba haciendo prueba de envió de información a través de sockets